# Java XML practice

Tags: java, xml, file, save, standards

I have an application that receives weather information every x seconds. I am wanting to save this data to an XML file.

Should I create a new XML file for each weather notification, or append each notification to the same XML file? I am not sure of the XML standards of what is common practice.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend appending not because that is a standard practice of XML, but more because creating a new file every x seconds will likely be a very difficult way to manage your data. You may also run into limitations of your file system (e.g. maximum files per directory).

You might also consider using a database instead of files to store your data.

Answer (score 0):

XML files have only one root element. You can write multiple XML fragments into the file but it won't be a valid document then. So while both options are fine, and you should consider your other requirements too, the standard somewhat nudges you towards writing a file (or a database row) per notification.